# Where does MacTeX store fonts in texmf?

Tags: fonts, xetex, texmf

Where does MacTeX store fonts in texmf? Specifically, I want to know where it stores XITS and whether or not I have to add it to the fonts list to use XITS with XeTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Terminal and execute `kpsewhich xits-regular.otf`. In my case this yields:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/xits/xits-regular.otf
```